# How to calculate a mean from a range of rows

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

Using a forloop, how do I calculate 5 sets of data to calculate for example the mean and standard deviation?

For example the array is

```py
data = np.array([[49, 32, 32,  8, 49],
                 [ 1, 29, 28, 45, 20],
                 [11, 40,  5,  6, 21],
                 [13, 45,  3, 12, 12],
                 [11,  6, 39, 39, 27],
                 [10, 34,  1, 15, 42],
                 [31, 27,  3,  4, 12],
                 [41, 14, 27, 45, 44],
                 [48, 37, 14, 16, 13],
                 [41,  9, 14, 49, 16]])
```

Shape is (10,5)

I need to calculate the mean and standard from 5 rows continuously using forloop?
My code only calculates the mean of each row:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    mean = np.mean(data[i])
    print(mean)
```

Comment: Why are you using numpy if you are going to use a loop?

Comment: Is this question "how to write a for loop" or is this question "how to calculate the mean and standard deviation of a sample?

Comment: You say you want 5 sets of data and that you want to calculate the mean of each row, but your array has 10 rows. Are you trying to find the mean and stdev of *a chunk of 5 rows at a time*?

Comment: @ddejohn Yes calculate 5 rows

Comment: That didn't clear anything up. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it quite easily without for loop like the following:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[49, 32, 32,  8, 49],
                 [ 1, 29, 28, 45, 20],
                 [11, 40,  5,  6, 21],
                 [13, 45,  3, 12, 12],
                 [11,  6, 39, 39, 27],
                 [10, 34,  1, 15, 42],
                 [31, 27,  3,  4, 12],
                 [41, 14, 27, 45, 44],
                 [48, 37, 14, 16, 13],
                 [41,  9, 14, 49, 16]])

mean = np.mean(data, axis=0) 
print("Mean:", mean)

stdev = np.std(data, axis=0, ddof=1) #remove "ddof=1" if you want to calculate STDEV of a Population, adding "ddof=1" means you want to calculate the STDEV of Sample.
print("STDEV:",stdev)
```

Output:
[image]